# Excel 2010 formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Does anyone know if there is an easier way to use the nested If statements other than what I am using below.

What I have is a column with 159+ counties in GA, and a column with data say AB or AG that I am trying to match but It would appear that I would need a nested If statement for each "county" - 159) and I believe the max is 64.

To write a formula like:

```
 =IF($C2="Autauga AL","AB",IF($C2="Baldwin AL","AG",IF($C2="Barbour AL","AB",IF($C2="Bibb AL","AG",))))
```

and to keep going would be a very long process.

To clarify column A is county, column B is spectrum and column C would be the result that I am looking for: for example,

cell A2 states Autauga, cell B2 states AB. I need to have a formula that would look at the data (A2 and A3) and return a result that if A2 =Autauga and A3 = AB return in C2 AB. the problem is that I have 159 + counties to do this for. Hope this helps.

Perfect - TY

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "a column with data say AB or AG that I am trying to match"? Do you have one column of data to match, or two? What sort of matching are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use data validation instead.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like `VLOOKUP` should work for you, e.g. if you have counties listed in A2:A160 and associated date in B2:B160 then you can use `VLOOKUP` like this in E2 assuming D2 contains a specific county

`=VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:B$160,2,0)`

You can copy the formula down if required